# Windows Server 2022 unattended install with xml answer file

Tags: windows, windows-server-2022

I'm trying to automate the Windows Server 2022 Installation by using an answer file.

I have created the following answer file for Windows Server 2022 in Windows System Image Manager:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<unattend xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:unattend">
    <settings pass="windowsPE">
        <component name="Microsoft-Windows-International-Core-WinPE" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <InputLocale>0407:00000407</InputLocale>
            <UserLocale>de-DE</UserLocale>
            <SetupUILanguage>
                <WillShowUI>Never</WillShowUI>
            </SetupUILanguage>
        </component>
    </settings>
    <cpi:offlineImage cpi:source="wim:c:/users/xxx.xxx/downloads/20348.169.210806-2348.fe_release_svc_refresh_server_eval_x64fre_en-us/sources/install.wim#Windows Server 2022 SERVERSTANDARDCORE" xmlns:cpi="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:cpi" />
</unattend>
```

I'm expecting this to automatically set the Keyboard input locale to german, and the time and currency setting to germany, and also not to show the locale selection UI.

I have then packed the `unattend.xml` file in an iso, so I can easily modify it without having to upload a 5GB ISO to the hypervisor (ESXI in this case). This iso is mounted for the VM I want to install Windows Server in, in addition to the installation iso.

When I'm booting the Windows Server 2022 ISO, I'm opening the console with Shift+F10, and then executing `setup.exe /unattend:e:\unattend.xml`. I have confirmed with `type e:\unattend.xml` that the file can be read correctly.

For some reason, the locale selection screen is still shown and the default values are selected (not the ones specified in my `unattend.xml`)

How can I get the Windows Server 2022 setup to correctly use the settings from the `unattend.xml` config?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved this and have a few observations:

**1st:** Naming the file `Autoattend.xml` leads to it being applied automatically, no need to use the `/unattend` option.

**2nd:** For some reason, `InputLocale` and `UserLocale` have no effect when `UILanguage` and `SystemLocale` are not set. Setting them to their respective default values fixes this.

**3rd:** If all options from `2nd` are set, the `WillShowUI` option is not necessary.